# Swap 2 SQL queries into one in Delphi XE7

Tags: sql, delphi

Is it possible to do the same thing in the code below with a single SQL query ?

```
Form2.que2.Active := false;
Form2.que2.SQL.Text := 'select ID from Gatunki where Gatunek = :nazwa ';
Form2.que2.Parameters.ParamByName('nazwa').Value:= ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex] ;
Form2.que2.Active := true;
idgatunku := Form2.que2.Fields.Fields[0].AsString;
Form2.que2.Active := false;
Form2.que2.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE books SET Tytuł = "'+Edit1.Text+'", year = "'+Edit2.Text+', IDGatunek = :idg where books.ID = :id';
Form2.que2.Parameters.ParamByName('id').Value:= id;
Form2.que2.Parameters.ParamByName('idg').Value:= idgatunku;
Form2.que2.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Could you tell on what kind of DB this query is being performed, SQLServer, MySQL, ... ?

Comment: Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Comment: Why are you not using parameters for **all** values?

Answer (score 1):

(**Edited v#2 / 2014-12-29**):

I've just tried another option and it worked on test db designed to match your case. If you could please try this version of the query:

```
Form2.que2.Active := false;
Form2.que2.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE books, Gatunki SET books.[Tytuł] = "' + Edit1.Text + '", books.[year] = ' + Edit2.Text + ', books.IDGatunek = Gatunki.ID WHERE books.ID = :id AND Gatunki.Gatunek = :nazwa';    
Form2.que2.Parameters.ParamByName('nazwa').Value:= ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex] ;
Form2.que2.Parameters.ParamByName('id').Value:= id;
Form2.que2.ExecSQL;
```

... and, again, please respond whether it worked.

Comment: That `MAX(ID)` was chosen by fair dice roll, right :) ? And please sanitize this code.

Comment: Yes, only for ensuring that there will always be a single salar value returned

Comment: What kind of dayabase do you connect to through the OLEDB?

Comment: Mircrosoft Acess (accdb)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you also tell whether this query: `select ID from Gatunki where Gatunek = :nazwa` always returns 1 record for a given parameter value? If not, which ID should be chosen: first of the set, or MAX(ID), ... ?

Comment: "Gatunek" is unique so the query will always return a single value.
Unfortunately, this does not work :( I get the error " join expression is not supported ." In other queries I use JOIN and it work.

Comment: Please find the edited answer - I've checked it on test db and it worked. I hope it helps.